# How to find the uptime since last wake from standby

Tags: linux, standby, uptime

I want to know the uptime since the last wake from standby.

The command `uptime` only shows the difference between current time minus the last startup time.

Answer (score 31):

In `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, look for the last line looking like this one:

```
Sun Dec 16 09:30:31 CET 2012: Awake.
```

That's your last wakeup time. You can calculate your uptime since then the way Paul suggested.

Periodically your `logrotate` will "rotate" logs to prevent them from growing too big, so you may find an empty `pm-suspend.log` file. In this case, just look for the `pm-suspend.log.1` file (you may find also other log files named like `pm-suspend.log.2.gz` and so on; you can examine them using `zcat` or `zless`).

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: What if `pm-suspend.log` is empty? :(

Comment: If you also care about suspend timestamp, use: `cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log /var/log/pm-suspend.log.1 | grep -B1 Awake; echo "--"; zcat /var/log/pm-suspend.log.*.gz | grep -B1 Awake`

Comment: No such file in my computer (running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: File is present only if you installed the pm-suspend. But for example Kubuntu goes to suspended state also after I close the notebook. Then the pm-suspend file is empty.

Answer (score 28):

The pm-suspend program is not the only option how to suspend the computer. My log of this program is now empty, but I have found more reliable command:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep 'systemd-sleep'
```

You can then filter by messages like `resumed` or `Suspending`, by adding another `grep`.

And the output is:

```
Oct  2 09:11:48 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[931]: Suspending system...
Oct  2 09:53:10 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[931]: System resumed.
Oct  2 15:02:48 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[27516]: Suspending system...
Oct  2 16:07:19 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[27516]: System resumed.
Oct  2 16:32:48 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[29622]: Suspending system...
Oct  2 17:16:41 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[29622]: System resumed.
Oct  3 00:24:58 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[21316]: Suspending system...
Oct  3 08:17:22 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[21316]: System resumed.
Oct  3 09:09:25 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[24739]: Suspending system...
Oct  3 09:50:47 dmatej-lenovo systemd-sleep[24739]: System resumed.
```

On newer versions of Ubuntu, this may instead look like:

```
Feb 14 16:42:03 ThinkPad-P15v-Gen-1 systemd-sleep[30594]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Feb 14 18:37:55 ThinkPad-P15v-Gen-1 systemd-sleep[30594]: System returned from sleep state.
Feb 15 17:14:06 ThinkPad-P15v-Gen-1 systemd-sleep[3441]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Feb 16 09:36:36 ThinkPad-P15v-Gen-1 systemd-sleep[3441]: System returned from sleep state.
```

Comment: I had to add -a to grep because I was getting `grep: (standard input): binary file matches` and some latest records were not shown. So the command which worked for me was - `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -a 'systemd-sleep' | grep "Suspending\|resumed"`

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, I had to update to `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -a 'systemd-sleep' | grep "Entering sleep state\|System returned from sleep"`

Comment: Yes, this is super useful.  Sometimes the computer would have earlier logs renamed to `syslog.1` and so on.

Answer (score 25):

None of these answers worked for me. But I usefully found `sleep.target` which is made for exactly this:

```
$ journalctl -n4 -u sleep.target
nov. 17 17:16:37 kaa systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
nov. 17 18:46:22 kaa systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
nov. 17 19:27:31 kaa systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
nov. 17 19:45:21 kaa systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
```

Comment: that's the only one that worked for me, too (using Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon)

Comment: @Suzana came with a tip for calculating the time since: `$ datediff -f%H:%M:%S  $(journalctl -n4 -u sleep.target -o short-iso | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 1) now` -> `5:38:48` (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/)

Comment: kinda useless use of tail and cut there, but ohwell ;)

Comment: So how would you get the timestamp without tail and cut?

Comment: @Suzana `cut` might be required here, but you can just use `-n1` to remove the tail, maybe also add `-q` so journal doesn't add warning messages messing up. It's also possible to use JSON and `jq` instead of cut: `journalctl -q -n1 -u sleep.target -o json | jq -r ._SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: `journalctl -n1` works only if you also add `-r` to get the newest timestamp but you are right, that's shorter.

Answer (score 24):

For desktops/servers running systemd, while there is no direct command that will tell the info directly (as far as I am aware), all the data is captured in the journal.

You can grep the journal, for example:

```
echo ">> [SUSPEND] Times during current boot"
journalctl -b 0 |grep "]: Suspending system..."
echo ">> [WAKE] Times during current boot"
journalctl -b 0 |grep "PM: Finishing wakeup"
```

Or, for fancy output, I wrote a python3 script (runs fine on Fedora 23)
Sample output:

```
Initial Boot Timestamp:  2016-01-15 09:31:32 

     Wake Timestamp     |    Suspend Timestamp   |       Awake Time       |
  --------------------  |  --------------------  |  --------------------  |
   2016-01-15 09:31:32  |   2016-01-15 09:36:03  |          0h  4m        |
   2016-01-15 09:36:22  |   2016-01-15 19:15:04  |          9h 38m        |
   2016-01-15 19:22:21  |   2016-01-15 20:00:05  |          0h 37m        |
   ...
   -------------------  |  --------------------  |  --------------------  | 

Summary: Days Since Boot [8.23] | Days Awake [4.14] | Suspend/Wake Cycles: [28]
```

The script is in github. [link to github repo](https://github.com/arigit/lastwake.py)

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Good to know that we can check the journal.

Comment: Use `journalctl -b 0 -o short-iso MESSAGE="PM: Finishing wakeup." | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f1` for just the time of the last wakeup

Comment: On Fedora, this worked for me: `journalctl -b 0 | grep "System resumed" | tail -1`

Answer (score 2):

I did not have pm-suspend.log on my machine.

This worked for me:

```
/usr/bin/pmset -g log | grep Wake | grep "due to" | tail -n1
```

Also says what woke the computer up. :-)

Comment: What if there's no command `pmset` found and no such file as `pmset` and `pm-suspend.log` is empty? :(

Comment: `pm-suspend.log` was missing and this works for me (on my iMac)

Comment: This is for Mac only

Comment: show perfectly in MacOs Catalina

Answer (score 1):

modified better verision of steps answer

```
grep ': Awake' /var/log/pm-suspend.log
```

edit haha thanks for the comments :D

Comment: And you won a useless use of `cat` point!

Comment: No upvotes for useless use of 'cat'.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to initiate the standby?

If you can use a script, then after the line

```
echo -n "standby" > /proc/acpi/sleep
```

you could have the line

```
echo `date +%s` >> /var/log/wakeups.log
```

Or something similar.  This would mean that the first thing the machine did when it woke up was to write the current time and date to a log file (n seconds since epoch).

Then `tail -1 /var/log/wakeups.log` would give you the last time.  You could could subtract this from the current time to get seconds since the last wakeup.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the last occurence of the string "PM: restore of devices complete" in /var/log/messages. If your machine has been up too long, then the log may be rotated, though.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Steps answer:

```
grep Awake /var/log/pm-suspend.log | tail -1
```

This will get the line with the last wakeup time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tuptime](https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime) for track the system startup/shutdown life.

Comment: Does not provide the information the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very solid way to do it:

`systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs at resume`

Search for when the OS starts anacron, will happen however the machine is turned on

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the last wake up time on Ubuntu 19.04 you can also:

`grep sleep /var/log/auth.log*`

```bsh
auth.log.1:Feb 29 17:49:12 systemd-logind[694]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
auth.log.1:Mar  1 09:39:01 systemd-logind[694]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
```

I add this answer because I don't have the `pm-suspend` file like other answers suggested using.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
journalctl -r -S "1 day ago" | grep "System returned from sleep state" | head -1 | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' | {read last_wake_up; echo $(($(date --date="now" +%s) - $(date --date="$last_wake_up" +%s)))} | {read sec ; eval "echo $(date -ud "@$sec" +'$((%s/3600/24)) days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds')"}
```

result:

```
0 days 07 hours 37 minutes 07 seconds
```

A bit shorter answer:

```
journalctl -r -S "1 day ago" | grep "System returned from sleep state" | head -1 | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' | {read last_wake_up; echo $(( ($(date --date="now" +%s) - $(date --date="$last_wake_up" +%s) )/(60*60) ))"h"}
```

result:

```
6h
```

(tested on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, kernel 5.15).

---

If you want to see minutes, change `(60*60)))"h"` to `(60)))"m"`.

If you want to see days, change `(60*60)))"h"` to `(60*60*24)))"d"`.

If you want to only see last wake up log, use:

```
journalctl -r -S "1 day ago" | grep "System returned from sleep state" | head -1
```

---

Please keep in mind that it's nice to have defined "since" `-S` in **journalctl** command, because there are a lot of logs there. On my machine I have **3 905 300** lines, and for the last day it's only **14 733**.

"Since" can also be defined as a `-S "2022-08-29 12:20"`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the kernel log to get the wakeup time.

```
wakeup=$(grep 'PM: suspend exit' /var/log/kern.log | tail -n1 | cut -c -15)
awake=$(( $(date +%s) - $(date --date "$wakeup" +%s) ))
```

This log ought to be pretty small and easy to search.

All the other answers either didn't work on my system (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) or required installing something else.

Answer (score -1):

on fedora using ripgrep

```
rg Suspend /var/log/messages
```

result:

```
34338:Jul 26 03:03:46 <hostname> systemd-sleep: Suspending system...
```